# Trying to refresh a TileLayer on OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have a TileLayer with TileWMS source like this:

```
this.imageLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new TileWMS({
    url: url,
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    params: params,
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    transition: 0,
    
  }),
});

this.map.addLayer(this.imageLayer);
```

All images are charging well on the map, but at some point im trying to create features, save them on my DB and then refresh my layer so the new features created will appear right after their creation.

I'm refreshing the layer like this:

```
this.imageLayer.getSource().refresh();
```

On the network tool I can see how the images are being asked to the server, but new features are not being rendered.

Why is this not working?

I have been making some tests, and when im creating the features and calling the method refresh() with the F12 tab opened, the tiles are rendered perfectly, but in a normal way, with the F12 tab closed, features are not rendered.

Comment: It is probably browser caching.  Either your server must set appropriate cache control headers or you could add and update a timestamp in the WMS params to force a refresh, for example `this.imageLayer.getSource().updateParams({'TIMESTAMP' : Date.now()});`

Comment: THANKS! It works like a charm, now my features are rendering after I create them!